# Does the fundamental group provide information about the topological space?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

Today I started to study about fundamental group by my own free will. I would like to know if it is possible to extract information about a topological space $(X, \tau_X)$ based on its fundamental group. This information I talk about is for example: The topological space is Hausdorff, connected or compact.

Comment: Consider the indiscrete and discrete topologies on an infinite set. The fundamental group is about more "algebraic" topological information, such as *simply* connectedness (which is just the question of whether $\pi_1$ is trivial).

Comment: For starters, the main concept you should come to terms with is homotopy equivalence; if two spaces are homotopy equivalent, then they have the same fundamental group. So you need properties that are preserved under homotopy equivalence. Connectedness is one; compactness most definitely is not.

Comment: The main purpose of the fundamental group is less about the topological space itself than comparison *between* spaces; I mean, homeomorphic spaces possess the same fundamental group, so that they are "topologically equivalent".

Comment: One way to put it is that if you consider Hausdorfness, connectedness, compactness **and** $\pi_1$ then you will have more information about the topological space than you have with Hausdorfness, connectedness, and compactness all by themselves.

Comment: In fact, Hausdorffness, connectedness, and compactness divide spaces up into only 8 different classes. But when you take all the possible different groups that can be isomorphic to $\pi_1$ then suddenly you've divided spaces up into infinitely many classes. MUCH more information.

Comment: Since every finitely-presented group is both the fundamental group of a compact manifold as well as the fundamental group of a space with finitely many points, in general no useful topological information is given by $\pi_1$. However, if you work with a restricted class of spaces, then the question becomes very interesting. For instance, if $M$ is a closed 3-manifold, then $\pi_1M=0$ if and only if $M\cong S^3$ (this is a very deep result).

Answer (score 2):

Of course the fundamental group provides information about the topological space, but not that mentioned in your question:

> This information I talk about is for example: The topological space is Hausdorff, connected or compact.

The fundamental group does not distinguish between homotopy equivalent spaces, and Hausdorffness and compactness are not invariant under homotopy equivalence. As an example consider a one-point space $X$ (which is compact Hausdorff), a two-point space $Y$ with the trivial topology (which is compact and non-Hausdorff) and $Z = \mathbb R$ (which is Hausdorff and non-compact). The fundamental group of all three spaces is trivial (i.e. has only one element).

Also connectedness cannot be detected via fundamental group. For example, a discrete space with more than one point is not connected and has trivial fundamental group  for each basepoint.

The fundamental group $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ only depends on the path-component $P(x_0)$ of $x_0$ in $X$ ( i.e. $\pi_1(X,x_0) = \pi_1(P(x_0),x_0)$). In a pathwise connected space $P$ the groups $\pi_1(P,p)$ are isomorphic for all basepoints $p \in P$, thus if you have good luck you can verify that a space is not pathwise connected if you find to points $x_1, x_2 \in X$ such $\pi_1(X,x_i)$ are not isomorphic. But the disjoint union of two copies of
a pathwise connected spaces is not pathwise connected and has the same fundamental group for each basepoint.